# RTCMultiConnection delay

Tags: rtcmulticonnection

Playing with https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/Scalable-Screen-Broadcast.html, I see that the delay between the transmitting and receiving ends depends on the screen resolution and is in general quite high (600ms on full HD and 300ms on 1366x768 on a weak computer, and 250ms on full HD on a very powerful computer). Measurements were done on a LAN so network latency is effectively zero.

Is there anything that can done to improve on that? Ideally, I am looking for 100ms for full HD and 50ms for 1366x768. Maybe some way to switch codec? Use GPU for encoding? Any other ideas?

One thing that comes into my mind is do

connection.processSdp = function(sdp) {
    sdp = remove_vp8_codecs(sdp);

to force useing h264. while i have no idea if it will make more good than harm.

Comment: facing the same issue